# Proving surjectivity and injectivity of two transformations, knowing the rank of their composition.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

I have got another question concerning linear algebra. The excercise is:

> Let $\DeclareMathOperator{Im}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\DeclareMathOperator{nullity}{nullity}T_1:\mathbb{C}^3\rightarrow\
>  \mathbb{C}^2$ and $T_2:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$. Given that $\rank(T_2T_1)=2$, p\
>   rove that $T_1$ is surjective and $T_2$ is injective.

This is how I tried to do it. Due to rank-nullity theorem:
$$\dim(\mathbb{C}^3)=\rank(T_1)+\nullity(T_1)$$
What is more:
$$\dim(\Im(T_1))=\rank(T_2T_1)+\nullity(T_2T_1)$$
As $\rank(T_2T_1)=2$, then $\dim(\Im(T_1))=2$. So that, as $\Im(T_1) \subseteq\mathbb{C}^2$ an\
d $\dim(\Im(T_1))=\dim(\mathbb{C}^2)$, then $\Im(T_1)=\mathbb{C}^2$ and so $T_1$ is surjective\
.

As $\rank(T_2T_1)=\dim(\Im(T_2T_1))=2$ and $\dim(\Im(T_1))=2$, then also $\Im(T_2T_1)=(\Im(T_1\
))$, so $T_2$ must be injective.

Does it make any sense? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rank-Nullity theorem implies that a linear map $T:\Bbb C^m\to\Bbb C^n$ is

- **injective** if and only if $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank T=m$
- **surjective** if and only if $\rank T=n$

Additionally, $T$ satisfies $$\rank(T)\leq\min\{m,n\}\tag{1}$$

Finally, recall that the rank of the composition $T_2\circ T_1$ is bounded above by
$$
\rank(T_2\circ T_1)\leq\min\{\rank(T_2),\rank(T_1)\}\tag{2}
$$
In our case we have
\begin{align*}
T_1:\Bbb C^3\to\Bbb C^2 &&
T_2:\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C^3 
\end{align*}
with $\rank(T_2\circ T_1)=2$. Equation (1) gives 
\begin{align*}
0\leq\rank(T_1)\leq 2&&0\leq\rank(T_2)\leq 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
and equation (2) gives
$$
2\leq\min\{\rank(T_2),\rank(T_1)\}\tag{4}
$$
But now (3) and (4) combine to imply
$$
\rank(T_1)=\rank(T_2)=2
$$
Hence $T_1$ is surjective and $T_2$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do we have to prove $(1)$ or just state we use it?

Comment: @marco11 I have no idea what the standards are for whatever course you are taking. This is, however, a very standard fact in Linear Algebra. This is a better question for your instructor/professor than for me.